# How to use the sum function in for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, sum

I am using the `sum` function in my loop.

After calling this function I am getting error:

> "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'num_children'"

```
class _InnerNode(_Node):
    def __init__(self, ctr_idx, level, radius, children):
        self.ctr_idx = ctr_idx
        self.level = level
        self.radius = radius
        self.children = children
        self.num_children = sum(c.num_children for c in children)
```

Comment: What type is the `children` parameter you are passing in to your `InnerNode`?

Comment: So `c` is already an `int`, why not just sum that?

Comment: How are you calling the function? the problem seems to be the following: you are using `c` which is defined as an integer and trying to access a member it does not have (being it an integer). Be sure to not have declared `c` in multiple places (i.e. in the class and then locally in the function)

Comment: @FrancescoBoi but `c` is just an artifact of a comprehension.

Comment: @quamrana sorry you are right: it is the iteration variable, but then I am expecting `children` to be an iteratable object: what types are its elements?

Comment: @quamrana children is list

Comment: ..of integers... then you just need `sum(children)`

Comment: .. or is it a list of `InnerNode`? Well, then, you haven't shown us your call site. Either way I assume that the problem is there.

Comment: actually i am working on PurTree Clustering and this code is under cover tree https://github.com/patvarilly/CoverTree/blob/master/covertree.py

Comment: Your code as posted is correct. Your `children` parameter to the constructor *should* be a list of instances of `_InnerNode`. You should have posted the full error trace to find out which call site is causing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

c is an integer not an instance of the class _InnerNode so the compiler can't find the attribute that's why it is throwing you an error (as said in the comments).

Since children is a list the correct code  for the last line is  :
`self.num_children = sum(c for c in children)`

Comment: Just `self.num_children = sum(children)`